# Active Directory Target User Delete Reconciliation not working

Tags: active-directory, identity-management, oim

I am trying the OOTB Active Directory Target User Delete Reconciliation job, (OIM11gR2PS3) but it does not seem to work.
It throws no events, and the Sync Token of the job remains empty.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: what error you are getting in the logs and scheduler page?

Comment: the job runs successfully. there are no errors. it just brings nothing!

Comment: Is user's accounts are getting revoked ? Any errors in connector logs and connector server logs?

Comment: No the accounts are not being revoked. No there are no errors. The job seems to run fine bit it doesnot reconcile any users. It returns with 0  users.

Comment: What is the count of users that are deleted from target?

Comment: Have you check oim_server1-diagnostic log file?